# Update expressions based of parameters

Tags: c#, mongodb

Using MongoDB and C# 8 .netcore3.1 and MongoDb driver (latest)

THE GOAL: I want to be able to create MongoDB update definitions generically using  arguments.

Assume I have the following class (db document)

```
public class DataParent
{
    public DataChild Child1;
    public DataChild Child2;
}

public class DataChild
{
    public DateTime ADate;
    public long ACounter;
    public DateTime BDate;
    public long BCounter;
}

public enum DataChildEnum { Child1 = 1, Child2 = 2}
public enum DataChildData { A = 1, B = 2}
```

And I have the following method

```
private UpdateDefinition<DataParent> CreateUpdate(DataChildEnum child, DataChildData data, DateTime time, long increment)
```

I want to be able to create a method (which I don't write DataChildEnum*DataChildData cases) to create an update definition to increment one of the `DataChild` counter and its matching date.

so for example:

```
CreateUpdate(DataChildEnum.Child1, DataChildData.A, <currentdate>, 5)
```

THE GOAL is that the method call will return the value of

```
Builders<DataParent>.Update.Set(x => x.Child1.ADate, <currentdate>).Inc(x => x.Child1.ACounter, 5)
```

another example:

```
CreateUpdate(DataChildEnum.Child2, DataChildData.B, <currentdate>, 20)
```

THE GOAL is that the method call will return the value of

```
Builders<DataParent>.Update.Set(x => x.Child2.BDate, <currentdate>).Inc(x => x.Child2.BCounter, 20)
```

I also don't want to change the scheme here and make an object out of Date and Counter since there could be different handling in these cases (for example ill add another field called AList and update it but I don't need BList)

Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? I don't really follow what your goal is, or what the issue is?

Comment: @John tried to make it clearer now

Comment: So you mean you want to pass in an `enum` value to provide the prefix for `〇Counter` and `〇Date`? Why not use a dictionary of enum<->object which contains `Counter` and `Date`?

Comment: as i said, I dont want to change the scheme, its a constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private UpdateDefinition<DataParent> CreateUpdate(
    DataChildEnum child,
    DataChildData data,
    DateTime time,
    long increment)
{
    var parentParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(DataParent));
    var childProp = Expression.PropertyOrField(parentParam, child.ToString());

    var dateProp = Expression.PropertyOrField(childProp, $"{data.ToString()}Date");
    var countProp = Expression.PropertyOrField(childProp, $"{data.ToString()}Counter");

    return Builders<DataParent>.Update
        .Set(Expression.Lambda<Func<DataParent, DateTime>>(dateProp, parentParam), time)
        .Inc(Expression.Lambda<Func<DataParent, long>>(countProp, parentParam), increment);
}
```

Comment: its too much specific. also the dependancy in strings makes it unsafe in case of field renaming/deleting.

Comment: @OriRefael This answer is based on samples of your question to show the idea. If you want more general solution there is no way but changing your models and use for example some interfaces and attributes. but at last the main idea is using expressions this way. you can generalize it as far as you want